# Logparser's tolerance of errors

Tags: logparser

I'm using LogParser's (awesome) -o:SQL parameter to write values to sql. The target table has a DateTime field - which matches the typical row in the source file. The source file is generated by log4Net into a .csv file where the header (required by log4Net) is:

```
<header value="DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception&#13;&#10;" />
```

means that the first row has literally, that string: `DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception` LP is fine with that. The problem comes in where log4Net repeats that header row. In that case, LP tosses the error pasted below. During my testing, LP seems tolerant enough with just a few of those lines and proceeds with importing the rows found below the offending header line.

But there comes a point where LP will toss **'Too many errors... aborting'** Hence, I'm needing either convince LP to ignore a row with **DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Message,Exception**, or i need to change the schema of the database to be varchar (which I'd like not to do).

How have other handled the problem?

```
Error while parsing field DateTime: Invalid TIMESTAMP value "DateTime":
  Invalid timestamp year digit 'D'
  LogFile "D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Logs\Web\log4netCSV.log", Row number
  27, Value "DateTime,Thread,Level,Logger,Mes"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the CSV input format, you can use the "comment" argument to trick LP into thinking that lines starting with DateTime are comments. For example:

```
-comment DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

A general-case answer is to set the -e: global switch to limit the number of errors you are prepared to tolerate. Explicitly setting -e: -1 should help in the case described above.

> -e: 
>   Specifies a maximum number of parse errors to collect internally before aborting the execution of the command.
>   The default value for this global switch is -1, which is a special value causing the SQL engine to ignore all parse errors and report only the total number of parse errors encountered during the execution of the command.